# How to perform automatic scrolling?

Tags: android

I am using scroller class for auto scroll of the text in edittext but after stopping the animation scrolling goes back to top of the text and i want it to stop at current position. How can i perform this task?
I am using this code for scrolling:

```
public void Scroll()
       {
        scroll = new Scroller(PromptModeActivity.this,new LinearInterpolator());
        length = prompt_text.getLineCount();
        scroll.computeScrollOffset();
        prompt_text.setScroller(scroll);
        int a=prompt_text.getBottom();
        scroll.extendDuration(scroll.getFinalY());
            scroll.startScroll(scroll_x,scroll_y,0,a+500,
                (400000)/ speedAmount); 

       }
```

and using scroll.abortAnimation() to stop scrolling.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format code by selecting it and pressing CTRL+K. Use the preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An animation is not what you want here. Instead, I believe you're looking for `ScrollView.pageScroll()`.

Comment: Well, what kind of layout do you have? You say you're scrolling, so what's the scrolling part? Do you have a TextView inside a ScrollView?

Comment: If you have text that is larger than the screen, wrap it in a ScrollView and use pageScroll. That definitely works, allows for smooth scrolling, etc. If you really don't want that, View also has `scrollBy` and `scrollTo`, but I believe a ScrollView will scroll in a smoother fashion.

Comment: Not much to send, really. Put a ScrollView around your TextView. Get the ScrollView in code via findViewById and call pageScroll on it.

Comment: can you hlp me in my one more problem regarding database

Comment: i am having a problem that i have created two tables in my database and on create of first activity, i called database to run cursor to fetch the table but it is not working. getting force close error

Comment: 1. If you get a force close, you need to post the logcat. 2. You need to start a new question for that.

Comment: @Ebomike @Nikki you can always come to the SO Android chat to discuss stuff,